# RegEx: How can I replace with $n instances of a string?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to replace numbers of the form 4.2098234e-3 with 00042098234. I can capture the component parts ok with:

```
(-?)(\d+).(\d)+e-($d+)
```

but what I don't know how to do is to repeat the zeros at the start `$4` times.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, 
Ross

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this with the find/replace feature of TextMate, if that's of any consequence. I appreciate that there are better tools than RegEx for this problem, but it's still an interesting question (to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it purely in regular expressions, because the replace string is just a string with backreferences -- you can't use repetition there.

In most programming lnaguages, you have regex replace with callback, which would be able to do it. However it's not something that a text editor can do (unless it has some scripting support).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that should be done with regex. That said, you *can* do something like this, but it's not really worth the effort: the regex is complicated, and the capability is limited.

Here's an illustrative example of replacing a digit `[0-9]` with that many zeroes.

```
    // generate the regex and the replacement strings
    String seq = "123456789";
    String regex = seq.replaceAll(".", "(?=[$0-9].*(0)\\$)?") + "\\d";
    String repl = seq.replaceAll(".", "\\$$0");

    // let's see what they look like!!!
    System.out.println(repl); // prints "$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9"
    System.out.println(regex); // prints oh my god just look at the next section!

    // let's see if they work...
    String input = "3 2 0 4 x 11 9";
    System.out.println(
        (input + "0").replaceAll(regex, repl)
    ); // prints "000 00  0000 x 00 000000000"

    // it works!!!
```

The regex is ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/je8Ny)) (slightly formatted for readability):

```
(?=[1-9].*(0)$)?
(?=[2-9].*(0)$)?
(?=[3-9].*(0)$)?
(?=[4-9].*(0)$)?
(?=[5-9].*(0)$)?
(?=[6-9].*(0)$)?
(?=[7-9].*(0)$)?
(?=[8-9].*(0)$)?
(?=[9-9].*(0)$)?
\d
```

---

#### But how does it work??

The regex relies on [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It matches `\d`, but before doing that, it tries to see if it's `[1-9]`. If so, `\1` goes all the way to the end of the input, where a `0` has been appended, to capture that `0`. Then the second assertion checks if it's `[2-9]`, and if so, `\2` goes all the way to the end of the input to grab `0`, and so on.

The technique works, but beyond a cute regex exercise, it probably has no real practicability.

Note also that `11` is replaced to `00`. That is, each `1` is replaced with 1 zero. It's probably possible to recognize 11 as a number and put 11 zeroes instead, but it'd only make the regex more convoluted.